# Angular how to global / application scope template

Tags: angular, templates, reusability

I need to reuse a parameterized menu template in many components to build up the local menu

```
<ng-template #menubutton let-link="link" let-icon="icon" let-text="text" ...>  
... does magic :)
</ng-template>
```

I tried to extract this part

1. into an injectable common-menu component
2. adding to app.component.html

but doesn't work and no any error.

pls put aside that this menu solution is very poor because the question can be generalized: how can we make application scope templates ?

Thanks in advance,

Csaba

Comment: app.component.html isn't an app-wide template it's just the default app entry point.

For your use you could make a directive that adds those attributes and add it to any required elements?

Comment: sorry i dont get the point, attributes are fix its data comes from json

Comment: Then make your template its own component and pass any values it requires as @Input properties. It's quite hard to understand what your use case is here without details of how you're currently using that template so we can see what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Ok, it needs an own component, on the other side it means we cant have global templates. (it would be much easier to put it into an application scope html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but here's how I do it in my Angular project for years.

We need a simple map of `TemplateRef` instances:

```js
import { TemplateRef } from "@angular/core";

export class TemplateStore {
    private templates: Map<string, TemplateRef<any>> = new Map<string, TemplateRef<any>>();

    public add(key: string, template: TemplateRef<any>): void {
        // The argument validation is omitted for brevity

        this.templates.set(key, template);
    }

    public get(key: string): TemplateRef<any> {
        return this.templates.get(key);
    }
}
```

And a directive that assigns a key to templates:

```js
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef } from "@angular/core";
import { TemplateStore } from "./template-store";

@Directive({
    selector: "[appTemplateKey]"
})
export class TemplateKey {
    constructor(
        private readonly template: TemplateRef<any>,
        private readonly templateStore: TemplateStore
    ) { }

    @Input("appTemplateKey")
    public set key(value: string) {
        this.templateStore.add(value, this.template);
    }
}
```

Then we put the global templates in the app component template:

```html
<ng-template appTemplateKey="avatar" let-user>
    <a routerLink="/{{user.id}}" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
        <img [src]="user.pictureUrl" alt="" loading="lazy">
    </a>
</ng-template>
```

And the usage:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateStore.get('avatar'); context: {$implicit: currentUser}"></ng-container>
```

The inconvinience here is that we need to inject the `TemplateStore` into every component that uses it. Since in my Angular project all the components inherit a base class, we can avoid the injection by putting in the base class a method like this:

```js
public template(key: string): TemplateRef<any> {
    return AppContext.current.templateStore.get(key);
}
```

The `AppContext.current` is a global object that holds a reference to the `TemplateStore`. So the usage become:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template('avatar'); context: {$implicit: currentUser}"></ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you sir :)